# How can I increase quantity and their prices according to cart of items in cart?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I tried this code and I have been using material UI for form and table cells. This code is displaying content on localhost:3000 but when I tried clicking on the increasing button the page disappeared, maybe I am not accessing the usestate function properly. here by using setProducts I tried changing values of quantity temporarily. It is a react code.

```js
const[products,setProducts]=useState([
            {
                'cartItems':[
                    {
        
                        name: 'Cherry',
                        quantity: 1,
                        image:"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/cherry-trio-with-stem-and-leaf-picture-id157428769?b=1&k=20&m=157428769&s=170667a&w=0&h=F1PxAjsNGhS0svv0t_kMRYdAE3UGISZD_BY066-SubU=",
                        price:200,
                    },
                    {
                        name:'Almonds',
                        quantity:1,
                        image:"https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/almonds-picture-id153711056?b=1&k=20&m=153711056&s=170667a&w=0&h=8exR9-QE1WweR4ijYM7XdlELsrKBYLQyi7ILRexnHg4=",
                        price :100
                    },
                    {
                        name:'Onions',
                        quantity:1,
                        image:'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/red-onion-slice-picture-id175448479?b=1&k=20&m=175448479&s=170667a&w=0&h=kcjadYpPSifmgaESFhA7EKVMdLmL-pXPhrwSvJM0o2U=',
                        price : 200
                    }
                ],
                'totalPrice':500,
                'count':3
            }
        
        
        
    ]);

const handleDecrement = (prod_name) =>{
        setProducts(products => 
            products[0].cartItems.map((product) =>
             prod_name===product.name ? {...product,quantity:product.quantity-(product.quantity > 1 ? 1 :0)}:product
            )
            
        );
       
      }
      const handleIncrement = (prod_name) => {
        setProducts(products => 
            products[0].cartItems.map((product) =>
             prod_name===product.name ? {...product,quantity:product.quantity+1}:product
            )
        );
        
      }
```

```html
// this is a react code and matrial ui is used in it
<TableCell align="left" size="small" width={10}>
     <form>
          <div class="value-button" id="decrease" onClick={()=>handleDecrement(product.name)} value="Decrease Value"><RemoveIcon/></div>
          <input type="number" id='number' value={product.quantity} />
           <div class="value-button" id="increase" onClick=         {()=>handleIncrement(product.name)} value="Increase Value"><AddIcon/></div>
      </form>
</TableCell>
```

strong text

Comment: products is an object not array, it's better you seperate cartItems as a state array, and then do something like 
function increaseItems(id) {
    setCartItems(currentItems => {
      if (currItems.find(item => item.id === id) == null) {
        return [...currentItems, { id, quantity: 1 }]
      } else {
        return currItems.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
            return { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 }
          } else {
            return item
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close. You are still mutating the state.

```
const handleDecrement = (prod_name) =>{
  setProducts((products) => {
    const np = [...products];
    const np0 = np[0] = {...np[0]};
    np0.cartItems = np0.cartItems.map((product) =>
      prod_name===product.name ? ({...product, quantity: product.quantity-(product.quantity > 0 ? 1 : 0)}) : product
    );
    return np;
  });
};

const handleIncrement = (prod_name) => {
  setProducts(products => {
    const np = [...products];
    const np0 = np[0] = {...np[0]};
    np0.cartItems = np0.cartItems.map((product) =>
      prod_name===product.name ? ({...product, quantity:product.quantity + 1}):product
    );
    return np;
  });
};
```